# What would happen if someone connected the output of a USB Charger/Power bank to a USB port on a laptop/PC?

Tags: laptop, usb, power-supply

I have a cooling pad that uses a type-A USB for power, it comes with a Type-A usb to another type-A USB cable. And since I use a power bank to power the fans since I don't want to drain the battery life or lose a port I was wondering what would happen if I accidental connected the Power bank to my laptop? a few times I've almost done this so I was thinking if its dangerous I rather just use my laptop's port.

Comment: This question *obviously* lacks research effort because you have all the things you need to see for yourself what would happen. :D

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski :D I don't wanna lose my laptop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely nothing would happen. Most laptops cant charge a power bank, so the worst scenario would be a charged power bank.

Comment: It's possible to run down the battery on one or both devices if you leave them plugged in and communicating.  The USB devices are supposed to negotiate "What kind of device are you?  Should I pass power to you?".  However, if both answer 'No', then they just stay up and running, which uses a small amount of charge.

Comment: Very true. Though in most cases both devices answer 'No'

Comment: Nice! my power bank could be dumb though :P That's a relief anyway!

Comment: Please mark the question as solved, by approving the answer. Glad we could help.

Comment: Power banks do not charge themselves over the Type-A (output) port, they usually have a different port (micro-USB) for charging itself function. So your remark about "most laptops can't charge a power bank" is wrong. As a matter of fact, any laptop will charge a power bank. Powerbanks usually are very unscurpulous, and will charge from "anything 5V". So you have right answer for a wrong reason.